# Dynamically changing cursor/setting cur files

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

How can I dynamically change the style of cursors on my div using JS or CSS?
Because I have multiple situations...
I've tried the code below:

```
    div.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
        if (tool == "BC"){
          div.style.cursor = "url(/icons/bc.cur)";
        }
        if (tool == "pan"){
          div.style.cursor = "url(/icons/pan.cur)";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry for that... updated

Comment: how you determine `tool` ?

Comment: That really doesn't matter. It just an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using conditional comments as in html5 boilerplate you could define this style (note the different syntax for newer browser — see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) for further information):

```
div.bc { cursor : url(/icons/bc.cur), auto;  }
div.pan { cursor : url(/icons/pan.cur), auto; }

/* style for IE<9 */
.lt-ie9 div.bc { cursor : url(/icons/bc.cur); }
.lt-ie9 div.pan { cursor : url(/icons/pan.cur); }
```

and, assuming for simplicity that your div hasn't any class applied, just change your js code like so:

```
div.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
    this.className = tool.toLowerCase();
}
```

---

This approach will ensure good scalability, since in case you have another cursor to list, the javascript doesn't need to be modified further, just add a new couple of css rules. Furthermore you will totally keep off css from javascript, thus your javascript has a better mantainability.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thanky you a lot!

Comment: no clue: try to use other file formats (e.g. gif/png) as fallback (before `auto`)